# RecyclerView - disable fling stop after touch

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a slot machine application and for this I'm using `RecycleView` as a rail. Therefore all touch\click\scroll events are disabled for `RecyclerView`.

And to make "spin" I used `RecyclerView.fling(...)` method since it has better animation.

**BUT** appearantly fling stops when I touch the recycler view. **Why? And how can I disable this?**

xml:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_rail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_4"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="@dimen/dp_16"/>
```

init of RecyclerView:

```
LinearLayoutManager mRailLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);       
mRailsBinding.rvRail.setHasFixedSize(true);
new LinearSnapHelper().attachToRecyclerView(mRailsBinding.rvRail);
mRailsBinding.rvRail.setLayoutManager(mRailLayoutManager);
mRailsBinding.rvRail.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewDisabler());
mRailsBinding.rvRail.addOnScrollListener(railScrollListener); //checking here for time when scroll ended
mRailsBinding.rvRail.setAdapter(mRailAdapter);
```

Adapter does nothing special. It just inits views and has no click\touch evenets on them.

RecyclerViewDisabler:

```
public class RecyclerViewDisabler implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean state) {}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just read documentation carefull and found solution. I was needed to consume `dispatchTouchEvenet` manually. See code:

```
public class UntouchableRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    public UntouchableRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public UntouchableRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public UntouchableRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true; //consume
    }
}
```